# Scalar Multiplication?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to make a `scalar_multiplication` lambda function but I can only get my first assert to work. I figure there is multiple levels of abstraction I need to account for but I'm stuck. Here is what I have so far

```
scalar_mult = lambda c, M: [x * c for x in M]

assert scalar_mult(1, [[1,2], [3,4]]) == [[1,2], [3,4]]
assert scalar_mult(2, [[1,2], [3,4]]) == [[2,4], [6,8]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list M has **two levels**, thus you need to iterate twice. With your current code

```
scalar_mult(2, [[1,2], [3,4]])
```

will result in

```
[[1,2,1,2], [3,4,3,4]]
```

as you are multipling each **element** of the first list by 2, and multipling **a list** in python, by an integer simply replicates it. So your code does

```
[1, 2]*2  # which equals to [1,2,1,2]
```

and saves is as a first element of the new list, then proceeds to the second one and does the analogous "error".

On the other hand

```
scalar_mult = lambda c, M: [[x * c for x in X] for X in M]
```

should work fine.